# What is the minimum modulus where the first $n$ values of Fibonacci sequence are still unique?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

Using the sequence $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 2, F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$

$$
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, \ldots
$$

What is the smallest modulus $M$ for each $n$ such that this sequence $S_n = F_n \mod M$ has no duplicates?

E.g., for the first $3$ numbers, $1, 2, 3$, the smallest satisfying modulus is $3$, generating $1, 2, 0$. Anything smaller has non-unique values in the output, e.g. $2$ would make $1, 0, 1$.

This is my specific case, with the Fibonacci sequence, but because of it I also became interested in whether it's possible to calculate such $M$s for arbitrary sets of numbers. I didn't want to ask that in case of $XY$ problem and it turning out to be impossible for example, but it would be cool to hear a little about this problem too.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is this what you mean? For given $n$ determine the smallest modulus $M$ such that the numbers $S_j = F_j \bmod M$, $1 \le j \le n$, are all distinct.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A natural first step might be to compute $M(n)$ for the first few $n$.

Comment: Take a look at OEIS A270151 https://oeis.org/search?q=270151&go=Search

Comment: @MartinR yes exactly

Comment: @paw88789 I think that's exactly what I want to calculate! Uses so many words I have never heard of

Comment: @paw88789 do you know whether those can be calculated directly from only the ${F(2), ..., F(n+1)}$ set?

Comment: @theonlygusti I do not know how to do a direct calculation. The length of the runs and the size of the jumps in the OEIS sequence do not show any obvious patterns as far as I can see.

Comment: If there is some nice formula, it would likely have been included in the OEIS entry. As no such formula is present, it is likely (but not guaranteed) that none is currently known.